# Input element render differently on my page

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have found an example for a file `<input>` element, which I would like to use on my website. You can see it [in this page](https://flowbite.com/docs/forms/file-input/), or in the image below:

[image: File input selector from example.]

I am using React, so I have to adjust the code ever so slightly (e.g. `class` => `className`), so in my code it looks like this:

```
<input 
    className="block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400" 
    aria-describedby="file_input_help" 
    id="file_input" 
    type="file" />
```

However, on my site it looks quite different. More specifically, the "Choose file" button looks quite off, as you can see:

[image: How it renders on my website.]

I have Tailwind 3.4.0 installed, which from what I can see should be fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems you overlooked the whole "flowbite" aspect.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I haven’t done a lot of frontend before…

Comment: The link you posted, where you got the input css from, it is on a site called flowbite.com. Here's their quickstart https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing Flowbite's CSS.

Compare without:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<input 
  class="block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400" 
  aria-describedby="file_input_help" 
  id="file_input" 
  type="file"
/>
```

To with:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.2.1/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input 
  class="block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400" 
  aria-describedby="file_input_help" 
  id="file_input" 
  type="file"
/>
```

I included the CDN link for the purposes of the StackOverflow inline snippet, but for the build version of Tailwind, you'd want to [follow their instructions as per their *Getting Started* page](https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/quickstart/#require-via-npm):

> ### Require via NPM
>
> Make sure that you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) installed.
>
> 1. Install Flowbite as a dependency using NPM by running the following command:
>
>    ```bash
>    npm install flowbite
>    ```
> 2. Require Flowbite as a plugin inside the `tailwind.config.js` file:
>
>    ```js
>    module.exports = {
>
>      plugins: [
>        require('flowbite/plugin')
>      ]
>
>    }
>    ```
> 3. Additionally to your own `content` data you should add `flowbite` to apply the classes from the interactive elements in the `tailwind.config.js` file:
>
>    ```js
>    module.exports = {
>
>      content: [
>        "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
>      ]
>
>    }
>    ```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. Which part points to the Flowbite CSS though? All of it looks like TailwindCSS to me.

Comment: Step 2 adds the Flowbite Tailwind plugin which will include its CSS.